# React Hook: Access to state inside an external function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

In a React app, I would like to have a function initiate a series of async calls and then have the ability to alter the state available to those calls as they run. As an example, I would let the user initiate a retrieval of 5 data files, which could run in the background and take minutes, but give them the option to abort the process or trim the total file count.

Here's an idea of what it could look like, but unfortunately this pattern doesn't seem to work:

```
function App() {
  const [halt, setHalt] = useState(false);

  return (
      ...
      <button onClick={() => longProcess(halt)}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={() => setHalt(true)}>Stop</button>
      ...
  );
}

async function longProcess(halt) {
  for (const fileid of files_to_get) {
    // For example, halt if the user clicks the Stop button during execution
    if (halt) break;
    await getDataFile(fileid);
  }
}
```

Ideally, I want to use pure functional components and to allow the async function to be available for use by multiple components. So I've been using React Hooks across the board. I have come up with 3 solutions, but none of them quite fit the bill:

- Using a class component, `this.state` will update asynchronously

  - [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-set-state-example-8n9tv)
  - Downsides: not a functional component, async function is tied to the component
- `useRef()` is [a suggested option](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

  - [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-54xvt)
  - Downsides: we no longer get re-renders, and is this a common useRef pattern?
- Pass the setter from useState, pass a function when calling it which will retrieve the current value

  - [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-f8bqf)
  - Downsides: seems VERY hacky :)

I'd be curious if there's any clean way similar to the 3rd example, that I just haven't come across in my limited React experience. Other suggestions welcome as well!

Comment: Why is it a problem to have the async function inside the component?

Comment: approach with `useRef` fits that case to me, why do you think it does not?

Comment: @Alvaro I'd like to be able to reuse this function across several components, as it can be pretty fundamental. A decent option is to make a generic function and then include a small wrapper in each component, but I'm curious if we can do better!

Comment: @skyboyer Yeah, it's not bad, and what I'll use for now. I don't like giving up the re-render though. For example, I'd like some kind of UI cue that the halt was recognized. Say we're in the middle of a single, long fetch and the user clicks 'halt', then it might be confusing if nothing happens. If there's an easy way to cause a re-render here, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a reusable function I would define it inside a Hook.

The following proposal uses `useState` to execute the function. We need `useState` to trigger a render when the value changes. This value will call the function from inside a `useEffect`.

It also uses `useRef` so that the process can start and later read its value, that could have changed during execution.

```
const App = () => {
    const { startProcess, stopProcess } = useLongProcess();

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <button onClick={startProcess}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={stopProcess}>Stop</button>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

const useLongProcess = () => {
    const stop = useRef(false);
    const [start_process, setStartProcess] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!start_process) {
            return;
        }

        const longProcess = async () => {
            for (const fileid of files_to_get) {
                if (stop.current) break;
                await getDataFile(fileid);
            }
        };

        longProcess();
    }, [start_process]);

    return {
        startProcess: () => setStartProcess(true),
        stopProcess: () => {
            stop.current = true;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: This is looking pretty promising! So let me see if I get it:  we're flipping the situation, so it's not components providing refs, but the wrapper to the async will provide the refs to the components. Can each component using this can make its own parallel calls and aborts? Or would it be restricted to one at a time? I definitely like how streamlined using the process is inside the component.

Comment: @DerekLarson, Im glad you found it useful. You can use the hook in different components and each will have its own state and ref. This means that each time the hook is used it will handle its own `longProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have no way of updating the `halt` state inside the `longProcess` function once it's called. So you could work with some `global` object to update the state but that is not best practice.

So maybe take a look at React's `useCallback` and other hooks, and maybe change your loop to recursively calling one of those hooks so maybe this can help to update the state. Hope this helps even though I don't know a solution right now.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not interested in modifying `halt` inside `longProcess`, but want access to any updates to `halt`. The `useRef` example I provided is my best effort to get this access, but I will look into the `useCallback`. Would you know if it can trigger a re-render of the component?